# Ext.plugin.SortableList doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sencha-touch

I'm using Sencha Touch 2.3.0 with my project. And my project needs Sortable list in it... simply drag/drop list items to change store sequences.

It seems `Ext.plugin.SortableList` exist for this exquisite functionality but I wasn't able to make it run as I wanted. Though I've added this plugin to my list, all items are stuck and doesn't move. Just same as before.

This is what I've implemented so far.

```
Ext.define('ImageGallery.view.ImagePreferences', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype: 'image_preference_view',

    requires: [
        'Ext.plugin.SortableList',
    ],

    config: {
        title: 'Image Preferences',

        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'list',
                disableSelection: true,
                style: 'width: 100%; height: 100%; border-top: 1px solid white; background-color: white;',
                itemTpl: '<div class = "m_li_preference">\
                                <div class = "m_switch_no_dp">OFF</div>\
                                <div class = "m_switch_yes_dp">ON</div>\
                          </div>',

                id: 'id_list_preferences',

                store: 'id_preference_store',

                scrollable: false,
                deselectOnContainerClick: true,

                plugins: [
                    {
                        xclass: 'Ext.plugin.SortableList',
                    }
                ]
            },
        ],
    }
});
```

Of course I don't think it can be done with such simple steps. So I hope anybody who has experience in this problem help me. Any instructions will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You might have to configure something in your store or on the list.

Comment: Please let me know in detail what things should I configure... thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the handleSelector config on the plugin:

```
plugins: [
        {
            xclass: 'Ext.plugin.SortableList',
            handleSelector: '.reorderlistitem'
        }
    ],
```

On my itemTpl I am then making sure there's an icon with class "reorderlistitem" for each item in the list, which I float to the right of the x-list-item with CSS. An icon of three horizontal lines below each other is what I think most users expect to see.

I am not sure if the sortable list will work with scrolling turned off. I had a lot of issues on non-standard list configs getting the plugin to work. Eventually I settled on infinite: true and standard scrolling and it works for me with these settings.

Comment: Sorry, I've tried that but no success. Nothing happened and just same as before.

Comment: the only other difference I can see is that I'm running 2.3.1... I can vouch that the sortable list definitely works with the above code snippet there!